# How to analyze RCT with different number of measures with mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, control-group

I have data from a RCT analyzing the effect of an intervention on students. The experimental group had 3 measurements: before the intervention, directly after the intervention and six months after the intervention. Although, the control group only had 2 measurements: before the inetervention and after 6 months.

Since the students are nested in class-rooms, I intend to analyze the data with mixed models.

My question: Does it make sense to analyze the whole data-set with all measurement points in a single analysis? Or should I conduct one analysis including only the data of the experimental group before and after the intervention for short time effects and another with both groups and the data before and after six months for long time effects?

I am wondering, how I can find out if the effects where short or long time if I conduct an analysis with all data together. And if it even makes sense not having a control group for the short time effects.

Thank you very much for helping me out with this!

Answer (score 1):

It does not really help to measure an outcome in only one group, if one is interested in the causal effect of the intervention, unless one is willing to make strong assumptions (e.g. that the effect of the intervention has the same size at both time points, or grows linearly in time, or something similar). Without making such assumptions (or alternatively using historical control information), it will be very difficult to say anything about the early time point.

If you imagine hypothetical outcomes (assuming there's no other differences between group we need to adjust for other than differences on the metric of interest before intervention), I imagine your willingness to make (sort of) definite conclusions about the early time point might differ a lot about the scenarios below (and you can probably come up with further scenarios).
[image]

How could the early timepoint still be useful, if you don't want to make assumptions? Perhaps for imputing missing data at the later timepoint (but one should investigate whether the different data collection per group might cause a problem here), otherwise not really.

I fail to see how analyzing the data separately by group would have any value for making causal conclusions about the intervention. One always evaluates an intervention for causal questions vs. what would have occurred without the intervention (or under an alternative intervention).

I'd also worry that some assessments can influence the performance on future assessments (e.g. training effect, where people might get better when taking similar tests repeatedly). With the study done this way, this might be happening and we have no totally convincing way to really exclude this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

In general longitudinal analysis for an RCT should use all available measures in each group and makes the missing at random assumption, and to adjust for baseline as a covariate (not use it as a follow-up measurement - see https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long.html).  A key ingredient to the RCT is making the non-intervention part of the design as identical as possible across groups.  That was not done in your case as one group has an extra visit, and things like Hawthorne effects can alter the response of that group.

If you can make unverifiable assumptions relating to this issue, then jettisoning the early measurement for the control group and proceeding with an ordinary ANCOVA may be possible for comparing groups.  This assumes you have complete data otherwise; any further differential missingness would really destroy the design.